# NP304 3onedata C# socket send directly from server to device.

Tags: c#, sockets, client

How can I send data from my C# socket program to my clients?

Currently I have two programs, server and client.

I start my server, then my clients connect to server, in this way they are connected together, but now I want to send directly from server to client?

As my client cannot start its own connection, of course I have IP and port of my client, how can I send data from my server to a client with known IP and port?

Thanks.

Comment: I entered that in Google and got 59 million results in 0.35 seconds :P And, why can't your client send data directly to the server?

Comment: because my client is not a computer, it is a device which gets inputs from an electronic device (through RS485 port) and gives me LAN port, so I think I should send my request from my server (computer) to my client (device), then the device can answer me

Answer (score 0):

Since your clients are not computer programs you can control, you really have no chance but to contact them from the server. If your clients can handle TCP communications, you need to treat them as servers, and Connect from the server to each client (open the socket on the server side, and Connect to each client IP and port).

It's possible that your clients understand UDP and not TCP. That is actually going to be easier for you, as you only need to create one UDP socket, and use SendTo to send a data to each client (one SendTo call per client).

Let's just hope your clients aren't stuck on the Ethernet level...

Comment: thanks but as I sad my client is a device which cannot connect to me! it is not a computer, so I should try to connect to it, is not possible at all?

Comment: oh thanks, now what is your suggestion? I'm really confused!! I've searched a lot, but cannot solve this problem

Comment: I posted another suggestion, but you might want to specify the kind of device that converts network to RS485, it would help to figure out what protocols it supports.

Comment: oh thanks I think my device can communicate with TCP, it is called NP304 3onedata, it has 4 inputs for RS485 and one LAN output (which is connected to my PC), also it created virtual com ports, does it help at all?

Comment: If it creates virtual COM ports on your PC, you probably want to use them to access your devices. Are there 4 virtual ports?

Comment: my converted device is a 4-port RS232/485/422 to Ethernet Serial server, it supports TCP/IP socket, UDP, HTTP, across gateway, router communication, TELNET and DHCP protocol, I my original device requires MODBUS request which should be send via this converter, how can I start servers on my device? my converter device is server and my pc program is client?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8571/discussion-between-ali-dotnet-and-zmbq)

Comment: There's really not much for me to add. I looked at the device's brochure, it supports TCP/IP, but you need to look at its manual for examples on how to configure it and access it from a PC. I can't help you with anything else...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that COM-ports are slightly easy to communicate than implementing TCP/IP protocol on your device. Could your device read/write its COM-port?

Comment: my converter device has no COM-port, it can create virtual COM ports on my system, I use LAN cable to connect my PC to converter device